# Expand pattern under cursor to all files matching it

Tags: vim, macro

Is there anyway to let VIM expand the glob pattern to all files that match it?

e.g when I type `*.c`, and press some key, it would become `a.c b.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `glob` function (`:help glob()`)

For example, this command

```
:nmap <leader>* ciW<C-r>=substitute(glob(@"),'\n',' ','g')<cr>
```

defines a normal-mode mapping that replaces the current word with space separated output of `glob`.  Note that it will clobber your `"` register, which should not be a big deal as long as you keep that caveat in mind.  Unfortunately, it does not result in a pretty display because file names themselves often have spaces and may even have newlines.

Comment: Or: `:nmap <leader>* ciW<C-r>=substitute(glob(@"),'\n',' ','g')<cr>`

Comment: @sch Yes that is probably more robust but does sacrifice the `"` register.  I'll put it in.